# How do I install to a USB stick from the same USB stick? with UEFI and SecureBoot?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I've received a new dell inspiron 13 7000 series from my company, I don't have administrator rights on it. I also have with me a personal 128GB USB drive. I'd like to install Ubuntu onto the USB drive so that when I want to use the laptop in my off time I can plug the flash drive in and boot Ubuntu, otherwise the system should be unchanged. I also have only the one flash drive with me to install from and install to. And last but not least I'd like to partition the flash drive so I can still use it to store and transport files. Can I pull this all off? How? Maybe a link to a tutorial?

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: A work computer entrusted to you without administrator rights is not to be fiddle with. You can't install to the same USB flash drive and 128GB is too big for a liveUSB anyway (up to 32GB is usable, more may not boot properly) and finally UEFI makes things harder unless you can change the boot order (you probably can't because the UEFI is most likely password protected). In a nutshell, it's not for your personal use.

Comment: From a technical perspective, it can be done, but it requires understanding how EFI boots. From an ethics and legal perspective, I agree with CelticWarrior. It's conceivable your employer would frown upon such activities, perhaps to the point of firing you, so I strongly advise against attempting this. It's far better to use your own computer for personal activities.

Comment: I honestly don't know why it was given to me without admin rights. This is a small company, only four of us, two bosses and two workers. I'm one of the workers. My only guess is that he was afraid I'd louse something up, or maybe contract a virus that starts sending porn to clients.

Comment: That's why I wanted Linux on my flash drive that would only boot when I manually trigger it. How could I mess up the hardware for normal personal use with Linux installed to a removable flash drive?The setup/UEFI menu is not password protected.